# How to change border color of a textbox that is inside a groupbox (if possible, through a button)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make the text box inside a group box to change border color when it is empty. Example below.

[image]

But when I did it in group box, it only works when the form loads but the color won't change..

[image]

The code:

```
Private Sub Groupbox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Paint

    With TextBox1
        Dim p As New Pen(If(TextBox1.Text <> "", Color.White, Color.Red), 0)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, .Left - 1, .Top - 1, .Width + 1, .Height + 1)
        p.Dispose()
    End With
End Sub
```

**REFERENCE**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRL4VqebXoU

https://visualstudiocodes.blogspot.com/2019/10/text-box-border-largest-vbnet-when.html

Comment: When the `TextBox` is on the form, you're calling `Invalidate` on the form in the `TextChanged` event handler of the `TextBox`. When the `TextBox` is on the `GroupBox`, what do you think you should be doing in the `TextChanged` event handler? Are you doing that? Also, you should not be calling `Invalidate` with no argument because that unnecessarily repaints the entire form or control. You should be passing a `Rectangle` that represents the smallest area that might have changed and thus might need repainting. That is the same `Rectangle` as you're drawing.

Comment: I `Validate` it..? Sorry, I really don't know the answer to that. Alright, so I should remove `Invalidate` if there's no arguments and the current `Rectangle` should stay, right?

Comment: It seems like you have made no real attempt to understand the code in the page that your second link leads to. Follow the link, read the code and understand it. What do you think those calls to `Me.Invalidate` do? If you don't know, why have you not tried to find out? Regardless, how is it not obvious? If the `TextBox` is on the form then you call `Invalidate` on the form. If the `TextBox` is on the `GroupBox` then you...? If you can't work that out then we're both wasting our time. You may as well ignore everything from "Also" in my first comment until you can understand this part.

Comment: That is why I'm here to ask a question? I tried to understand what does it mean before using those codes in my program and there are some parts that I still can't figured it out, that's why I'm here. `If the TextBox is on the GroupBox then you...?` I would love to continue that sentence, but unfortunately, I already mentioned that I really don't know the answer to that.

Comment: I changed one word between *"If the `TextBox` is on the form"* and *"If the `TextBox` is on the `GroupBox`"*. How can it not be obvious that you need to change the same work in *"you call `Invalidate` on the form"*, i.e. *"you call `Invalidate` on the `GroupBox`"*? That's just basic language so it doesn't require any programming knowledge at all.

Comment: Got my answer from a post that was asked 6 years ago, thanks anyway.